# web.config location tag

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking to deploy a web app and I have a simple question about the `<location`> tag of the web.config file. For the moment, I want all the pages to be password protected and I've created a simple login page with the login object. I've put all my .aspx file in a directory called AppMyPages and I've put this in the config file:

```
<location path="AppMyPages">

    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="tester" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>

</location>
```

If I want to fully protect my site, do I need to do the same thing for all the other folders (AppCode, AppData, MyJavascripts, MyStylesheets, MyImages....)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do AppCode/AppData, but you need to be careful restricting the MyJavascripts/Stylesheets/Images if any of those resources are used on unauthenticated pages (e.g. Login page).

Comment: ok, thanks. For the moment, I'm just doing a limited private release so I'll include those. I've put my master page in a directory called Master: should I also include this one too if I want total security?

Comment: It's fine to leave the Master directory out.  Master pages aren't served directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this writeup about the location tag in a web.config and I found it enlightening.  I add this oly to help people find it when searching.  The Elmah tool we use here but the write up is not specific to it.

https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-location-element-demystified/